Csharpier does not change line lengths
Im reading this tool is suppose dto set line lengths to 80 characters by default
I ran it on my c# application, using instructions from here:
https://csharpier.com/docs/About
dotnet tool install csharpier

dotnet csharpier .

I got a message that it changed contents of 3 files.
Upon opening the files I found that none of the line lengths were modified
I need them to be 80 characters maximum
How can I enable this feature in CSharpier?
I tried adding a .csharpierrc.yaml file to the root directory, per instructions I also tried renaming to csharpierrc.yaml
The contents of the file are:
# 80 instead of default 100 for a few reasons:
# - discourages long names & deep nesting
# - makes side by side diffs more readable
# - matches prettier default
printWidth: 80
useTabs: false
tabWidth: 4
preprocessorSymbolSets:
    - ""
    - "DEBUG"


Considering the tags you had added to the question, can you confirm you're using Visual Studio?

Use Beyond Compare and verify that nothing has change between original and new file.  Make sure Beyond Compare shows white spaces.

What DID it change in those files? Also: those reasons for an 80 character limit are kinda weak. I just checked, and my monitor fits more than 230 characters across, so the default 100 character lines can still easily do the diffs, and there are better ways to discourage nesting.
